# Laravel ORDER BY rand FROM last [..] records

Tags: php, laravel, random

I have this code, yes, it show random, but how to make random from LAST 30 records from table, and if the table will dont have enough records dont be error?

```
    $galleries = DB::table('galleries')->select( DB::raw('galleries.*') )
        ->where( 'domain_id', $domain_id )
        ->where( 'is_deleted', 0 )
        ->whereNotIn('id', array_keys( Session::get("export_selected"  ) ) )
        ->whereNotIn('id',             Session::get("export_skip"      )   )
        ->whereNotIn('id', array_keys( Session::get("export_delete"    ) ) )
        ->whereNotIn('id', array_keys( Session::get("export_delete_all") ) )
        ->leftJoin('history', function($join) use ( $site_id ) {
            $join->where('history.site_id', '=', $site_id )
                 ->on('history.gallery_id', '=', 'galleries.id');
        })
        ->whereNull('history.gallery_id')
        ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
        ->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: use `->limit(30)` before you `orderBy` ?

Comment: yes, i tried , but dont work good
...
        ->whereNull('history.gallery_id')
        ->limit(30)
        ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
        ->take(10)->get();

Comment: `->take(10)->orderByRaw('RAND()')->get();`

Comment: tried like you say, but RAND totally dont work in second comment, on first comment dont work LIMIT

Comment: on first comment RAND works, but he uses full table...

Comment: I'd suggest to use builtin `->inRandomOrder()` instead of `->orderByRaw('RAND()')`